# Question about multiple scales approximation for a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, perturbation-theory

I have been trying to apply the method of multiple scales to a certain set of partial differential equations, but I keep having problems.  I would appreciate if someone could point out my mistake, whether in my application of the method or in my interpretation of the results.  I apologize about the length of the post, but I wanted to include my full derivation.

The relevant equations may be written as
\begin{gather}
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i\epsilon a(x)g = 0, \\
  \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - i\epsilon b(x)f = 0,
\end{gather}
where $\epsilon\ll1$ and $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are statistically homogeneous, positive and integrable functions (e.g., they could take the form $a(x)=1+\sin(kx)/4$).  If I assume that $f(x)=f_0(x_0,x_1,x_2)+\epsilon f_1(x_0,x_1,x_2) + \epsilon^2 f_2(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ and similarly for $g(x)$, where $x_n=\epsilon^n x$, and if I further assume that $f_n$ and $g_n$ are $O(1)$, I get an series of sets of differential equations.  The $O(1)$ equations may be written as
\begin{gather}
  \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial x_0} = \frac{\partial g_0}{\partial x_0} = 0,
\end{gather}
and so we find that the largest-scale approximation of $f$ and $g$ does not depend on the smallest length scale, $x_0$.  The $O(\epsilon)$ equations are
\begin{gather}
  \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_0} + \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial x_1} - i a(x_0)g_0 = 0, \\
  \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_0} + \frac{\partial g_0}{\partial x_1} - i b(x_0)f_0 = 0.
\end{gather}
Since $f_0$ and $g_0$ do not depend on $x_0$, we may integrate, yielding
\begin{gather}
  f_1 + x_0\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial x_1} - i g_0\int a(x')dx' + c_1 = 0, \\
  g_1 + x_0\frac{\partial g_0}{\partial x_1} - i f_0\int b(x')dx' + c_2 = 0,
\end{gather}
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants of integration.  These constants may be set equal to zero without loss of generality, as they may be incorporated into $f_0$ and $g_0$.  We need to remove secular terms.  Clearly, the $x_0$ terms are secular, but the integrals over $a$ and $b$ are also secular.  If we decompose $a(x_0)$ and $b(x_0)$ such that $a(x_0)=\langle a\rangle + \Delta a(x_0)$, where $\langle a\rangle$ is the average of $a(x_0)$, and $b(x_0)=\langle b\rangle + \Delta b(x_0)$, we may then write
\begin{gather}
  f_1 + x_0\left[\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial x_1} - ig_0\langle a\rangle\right] - i g_0\int_0^{x_0} \Delta a(x_0)dx_0 = 0, \\
  g_1 + x_0\left[\frac{\partial g_0}{\partial x_1} - if_0\langle b\rangle\right] - i f_0\int_0^{x_0} \Delta b(x_0')dx_0' = 0.
\end{gather}
Now the integrals are not secular, and we may set the terms in the square brackets equal to zero.  Thus, we may write
\begin{gather}
  f_1 = i g_0\int_0^{x_0} \Delta a(x_0)dx_0, \\
  g_1 = i f_0\int_0^{x_0} \Delta b(x_0)dx_0, \\
  \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial x_1} - i\langle a\rangle g_0 = 0, \\
  \frac{\partial g_0}{\partial x_1} - i\langle b\rangle f_0 = 0.
\end{gather}
Thus, I have equations for $f_0$ and $g_0$ that may be explicitly solved as a function of $x_1$.  I can then write the solutions as
\begin{gather}
  f_0(x_1,x_2) = A(x_2)e^{i\sqrt{\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle}x_1} + B(x_2)e^{-i\sqrt{\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle}x_1}, \\
  g_0(x_1,x_2) = \sqrt{\frac{\langle b\rangle}{\langle a\rangle}}A(x_2)e^{i\sqrt{\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle}x_1} - \sqrt{\frac{\langle b\rangle}{\langle a\rangle}}B(x_2)e^{-i\sqrt{\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle}x_1}.
\end{gather}

To this point I do not think there is an issue, but I would like to extend the results to higher orders.  The $O(\epsilon^2)$ equations are given by
\begin{gather}
  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_0} + \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial x_2} - i a(x_0)g_1 = 0, \\
  \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_0} + \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial g_0}{\partial x_2} - i b(x_0)f_1 = 0.
\end{gather}
Substituting in the solutions to $f_1$ and $g_1$ and their $x_1$ gradients then yields
\begin{gather}
  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_0} + \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial x_2} + \left[ a(x_0)\int_0^{x_0} \Delta b(x_0')dx_0' - \langle b\rangle \int_0^{x_0} \Delta a(x_0')dx_0' \right] f_0 = 0, \\
  \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_0} + \frac{\partial g_0}{\partial x_2} + \left[ b(x_0)\int_0^{x_0} \Delta a(x_0')dx_0' - \langle a\rangle \int_0^{x_0} \Delta b(x_0')dx_0' \right] g_0 = 0.
\end{gather}
We may integrate with respect to $x_0$ again, and eliminating the secular terms leads to the conclusion
\begin{gather}
  \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial x_2} + \left[ \left\langle a(x_0)\int_0^{x_0} \Delta b(x_0')dx_0'\right\rangle - \langle b\rangle \left\langle \int_0^{x_0} \Delta a(x_0')dx_0' \right\rangle \right] f_0 = 0, \\
  \frac{\partial g_0}{\partial x_2} + \left[ \left\langle b(x_0)\int_0^{x_0} \Delta a(x_0')dx_0'\right\rangle - \langle a\rangle \left\langle \int_0^{x_0} \Delta b(x_0')dx_0' \right\rangle \right] g_0 = 0.
\end{gather}
These equations may also be solved explicitly.  If we let
\begin{gather}
  \alpha \equiv \left\langle a(x_0)\int_0^{x_0} \Delta b(x_0')dx_0'\right\rangle - \langle b\rangle \left\langle \int_0^{x_0} \Delta a(x_0')dx_0' \right\rangle, \\
  \beta \equiv \left\langle b(x_0)\int_0^{x_0} \Delta a(x_0')dx_0'\right\rangle - \langle a\rangle \left\langle \int_0^{x_0} \Delta b(x_0')dx_0' \right\rangle,
\end{gather}
then the solutions are given by
\begin{gather}
  f_0(x_1,x_2) = f_{01}(x_1)e^{-\alpha x_2}, \\
  g_0(x_1,x_2) = g_{01}(x_1)e^{-\beta x_2}.
\end{gather}
Combining this result with the $O(\epsilon)$ result leads to the conclusions
\begin{gather}
  A(x_2) = B(x_2) = C_0e^{-\alpha x_2}, \\
  A(x_2) = B(x_2) = D_0e^{-\beta x_2}.
\end{gather}
However, both of these statements can only be true if $\alpha=\beta$, which is not always the case, or if $C_0=D_0=0$, which is the trivial solution.  I know that a non-trivial solution can exist for the original equations, even when $\alpha\ne\beta$.

Did I make a mistake somewhere?  Is there a restriction on the method of multiple scales that makes may analysis invalid?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The perturbation is regular, why is a simple perturbation series, without time scales, not sufficient? Why do you think you need a slower scale?

Comment: The regular perturbation leads to secular terms.  I thought that if I included additional scales I would be able to get rid of the secular terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bottom Line Up Front**

I think I have figured out the issues; there are a couple of them.  First, I discarded ``constants'' of integration when I should have retained them, and then I messed up the identification of secular terms.

---

**Corrected Derivation**

I think it may be easier to state writing everything in matrix form.  Let $\vec F=[f,g]^T$ and $\mathsf A=[0,a(x);b(x),0]$, such that the initial problem may be written as
$$ \frac{d\vec F}{dx} = i\epsilon\mathsf A\cdot\vec F. $$
By the multiple scales approximation we write
$$\vec F = \vec F_0(x_0,x_1,\cdots) + \epsilon\vec F_1(x_0,x_1,\cdots) + \cdots, $$
leading to the first three equations being written as
\begin{gather}
  \frac{d\vec F_0}{dx_0} = 0, \tag{1} \\
  \frac{d\vec F_0}{dx_1} + \frac{d\vec F_1}{dx_0} = i\mathsf A\cdot\vec F_0, \tag{2} \\
  \frac{d\vec F_0}{dx_2} + \frac{d\vec F_1}{dx_1} + \frac{d\vec F_2}{dx_0} = i\mathsf A\cdot\vec F_1. \tag{3}
\end{gather}
Equation (1) simply states that $\vec F_0$ is independent of $x_0$.  Using the notation of the original post we write $\mathsf A = \left\langle\mathsf A\right\rangle + \Delta\mathsf A$, and so we may solve Eq. (2) as
\begin{equation}
  \vec F_1 = -x_0\left[ \frac{d\vec F_0}{dx_1} - i\left\langle\mathsf A\right\rangle\cdot\vec F_0 \right] + i\int_0^{x_0}\Delta\mathsf A(x_0')dx_0'\cdot\vec F_0 + \vec F_{10},
\end{equation}
where $\vec F_{10}$ is the constant of integration.  **In the original post I assumed that $\vec F_{10}$ may be set equal to zero, but this assumption was my first mistake.**  In reality, $\vec F_{10}$ is a function of $x_1$, $x_2$, etc., and including it will be critical to continue.

As in the original post, the secular terms are set equal to zero, leading to the equation
$$ \frac{d\vec F_0}{dx_1} - i \left\langle\mathsf A\right\rangle\cdot\vec F_0 = 0. $$
To solve this we diagonalize $\left\langle\mathsf A\right\rangle$, such that we may write $\left\langle\mathsf A\right\rangle = \mathsf V\cdot\mathsf\Lambda\cdot\mathsf V^{-1},$ where $\mathsf \Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and $\mathsf V$ is the matrix of eigenvectors, which may be written as
\begin{gather}
  \mathsf\Lambda = \left[\begin{matrix} \sqrt{\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle} & 0 \\ 0 & -\sqrt{\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle} \end{matrix}\right], \\
  \mathsf V = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ \sqrt{\langle b\rangle/\langle a\rangle}  & -\sqrt{\langle b\rangle/\langle a\rangle} \end{matrix}\right], \\
  \mathsf V^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\langle a\rangle}{\langle b\rangle}}\left[\begin{matrix} \sqrt{\langle b\rangle/\langle a\rangle} & 1 \\ \sqrt{\langle b\rangle/\langle a\rangle}  & -1 \end{matrix}\right].
\end{gather}
Defining $\vec G_0=\mathsf V^{-1}\cdot\vec F_0$, the equation then becomes
$$ \frac{d\vec G_0}{dx_1} - i\mathsf\Lambda\cdot\vec G_0 = 0, $$
which is a set of two independent equations, and be may solve this by
$$ \vec G_0 = \exp\left[i\mathsf\Lambda x_1\right]\cdot\vec G_{00}, $$
where $\vec G_{00}$ is independent of $x_0$ and $x_1$.  This conclusion is identical to that given in the original post.

Equation (3) now reads
$$ \frac{d\vec F_0}{dx_2} - \int_0^{x_0}\Delta\mathsf A(x_0')dx_0'\cdot\left\langle\mathsf A\right\rangle\cdot\vec F_0 + \frac{d\vec F_{10}}{dx_1} + \frac{d\vec F_2}{dx_0} = -\mathsf A\cdot\int_0^{x_0}\Delta\mathsf A(x_0')dx_0'\cdot\vec F_0 + i\mathsf A\cdot\vec F_{10}. $$
Again, we desire to remove secular terms, and so we conclude
$$ \frac{d\vec F_{10}}{dx_1} - i\left\langle\mathsf A\right\rangle\cdot\vec F_{10} = - \frac{d\vec F_0}{dx_2} + \mathsf B\cdot\vec F_0 , $$
where
$$ \mathsf B = \left\langle\int_0^{x_0}\Delta\mathsf A(x_0')dx_0'\right\rangle\cdot\left\langle\mathsf A\right\rangle - \left\langle\mathsf A\cdot\int_0^{x_0}\Delta\mathsf A(x_0')dx_0'\right\rangle. $$
This last equation is the same as in the original post except for the inclusion of the $\vec F_{10}$ terms.  We may transform this equation as we did the $\vec F_0$ equation above using $\mathsf\Lambda$ and $\mathsf V$, yielding
$$ \frac{d\vec G_{10}}{dx_1} - i\mathsf \Lambda\cdot\vec G_{10} = - \frac{d\vec G_0}{dx_2} + \mathsf V^{-1}\cdot\mathsf B\cdot\mathsf V\cdot\vec G_0 , $$
where $\vec G_{10}=\mathsf V^{-1}\cdot\vec F_{10}$.  Substituting in the solution to $\vec G_0$ then yields
$$ \frac{d\vec G_{10}}{dx_1} - i\mathsf \Lambda\cdot\vec G_{10} = - \exp\left[i\mathsf\Lambda x_1\right]\cdot\frac{d\vec G_{00}}{dx_2} + \mathsf V^{-1}\cdot\mathsf B\cdot\mathsf V\cdot\exp\left[i\mathsf\Lambda x_1\right]\cdot\vec G_{00} . $$
The homogeneous solution for $\vec G_{10}$ is similar to that for $\vec G_0$.

At this point I am struggling to present a completely general explanation in terms of matrices and vectors.  The basic idea is that if there are terms including $e^{i\lambda_i x_1}$ in the $i$th equation they will lead to secular solutions.  Thus, it is not the entire right-hand side that must be equal to zer, but simply these terms.  **(This is the second major error I made in the original post.)**  Clearly, the first term on the right leads to secular terms, but only the diagonal terms of the matrix of the second term must.  Note that $\mathsf B$ is diagonal, and so we may write $\mathsf B=[c_1,0;0,c_2]$.  Explicitly performing the matrix multiplication then yields
$$ \mathsf V^{-1}\cdot\mathsf B\cdot\mathsf V\cdot\exp\left[i\mathsf\Lambda x_1\right] = \frac{1}{2} \left[\begin{matrix} (c_1+c_2)e^{i\lambda_1 x_1} & (c_1-c_2)e^{i\lambda_2x_1} \\ (c_1-c_2)e^{i\lambda_1 x_1} & (c_1+c_2)e^{i\lambda_2x_1} \end{matrix}\right]. $$
Thus, the actual constraint to avoid secular terms is given by
$$ \frac{d\vec G_{00}}{dx_2} - \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left[\mathsf B\right]\vec G_{00} = 0, $$
where $\mathrm{tr}[\mathsf B]$ is the trace of $\mathsf B$.  Solving this equation yields
$$ \vec G_{00} = e^{(\mathrm{tr}[\mathsf B]/2)x_2}\vec G_{000}, $$
where $\vec G_{000}$ is not a function of $x_0$, $x_1$, or $x_2$.  Substituting this into $\vec G_0$ we obtain
$$ \vec G_0 = \exp\left[i\mathsf\Lambda x_1 + \mathsf I\frac{\mathrm{tr}[\mathsf B]}{2}x_2\right]\cdot\vec G_{000}, $$
where $\mathsf I$ is the identity matrix, and finally we obtain the contradiction-free solution
$$ \vec F_0 = \mathsf V\cdot\exp\left[i\mathsf\Lambda x_1 + \mathsf I\frac{\mathrm{tr}[\mathsf B]}{2}x_2\right]\cdot\mathsf V^{-1}\cdot\vec F_{000}, $$
where $\vec F_{000}$ is not a function of $x_0$, $x_1$, or $x_2$.  We could break this solution out into individual expressions for $f_0$ and $g_0$, but I feel that it is unnecessary and tedious, so I will not do that here.